# Import is not recognized as internal and external command even after using "python"

Tags: python, cmd, nltk, importerror

I was trying to download nltk and import it as per the guidelines, I downloaded it but the problem was with importing[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMHuZ.png)

---

---

I tried using python and start>python311 but still it showed import is not recognized

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuQnh.png)

I even tried managing app exclusion aliases, so what should I do now, is there any other way to import nltk or fix this import problem

Comment: Type `python` and press enter before typing `import nltk` - you are currently just running in the command-line which is *not* Python.

Comment: You need to start an interactive python console before you can use things like 'import' in this way

Comment: Note that screenshots don't count towards meeting [MRE] requirements -- everything needed to answer a question should be included **as text** for the reasons given in [Why not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First you should run `python` command in your `cmd.exe` interpreter;
after that you should run `import nltk`.

Hope this one helps, because for importing a Python package you must call it in `python`.

Comment: Only code should be in backticks. The phrase "Python package" is a technical term, but it isn't code

Comment: i did it, still it shows import is not recognized